# What can you tell about this form input when it gives internal error with ';--' and not ';--?

Tags: sql-injection

I am doing a black-box test on a website. It has a form and i was testing it with different inputs. When i enter some specific inputs, it returns internal error.

Some inputs that give internal error:

- `';--'`
- `';---'`

Some inputs that doesn't give error:

- `';--`
- `';-f-'`
- `";--"`
- `;--'`

As you can see it's not a normal SQL injection flaw. If it was a normal SQL injection, results for `';--` and `';--'` and `';-- '` should not differ.

If you have any insights in the way that this input is tested or the flaw that i am dealing with. Btw I can test more inputs if necessary.

Comment: This seems a bit like 'do my pentest for me'?

Comment: i am doing my pentest. i just needed a simple help. isn't here about this?

Comment: @ananda I would check if there is not a replace to swap ' for " in the code.

Comment: @ThalesPereira No, there isn't.

Comment: It sounds like the script expects to receive a closing single-quote, and that there may also be some other string processing. Please try a) a two 2000-character long string of letters, followed by a single quote then semicolon b) ' AND 1=1;

Comment: @JonahB none of them give internal error.

Comment: Great. Try these: a) '; SELECT 1; b) ' AND nonsense=1; The first should succeed and the second should fail.

Comment: @JonahB no. none of them give internal error either. This is the reason i am saying it is not normal. it seems either the checking is different or they are using different method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried to explain it in similar lines of SilverlightFox answer using some spaces in sql query construction.

But, with that approach i am unable to explain why `';-f-'`  and  `' AND nonsense=1`  didn't  produce an Internal error.

So, I guess the Internal error is not actually caused by a DB Sql error.

Its caused by a sanitising function applied on userinput. Php Example using [preg-match](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) below.

```
function inputSanitiser($userinput)
{
$string1=$userinput;
$semicolonExist=preg_match("/';--/",$string1); //search for location(int) of ';-- in $string 1

$string2 =substr ( $string1 , stripos ( $string1 , "';--")+3); //substring from $string1 after the location  ';-- to end of $string1
$commentCloseExist=preg_match("/'/",$string2); //search for location(int) of ' in $string2


    if($commentCloseExist&&$semicolonExist)
    {
        produceInternalError();
    }
    else
    {
        runDbQuery($string1); //runDbQuery will not through Internal error and will silently fail
    }

}
```

Simply put, the `inputSanitiser` function is checking for few patterns like

> `';--`  followed by  `'`
>
> and may be `' UNION '` anywhere in the string

and few others.So, I guess `';--somethinghere--'` and `';--somethinghere-'` should also produce a Internal error.

Comment: This is a very great answer.`';--somethinghere--'` did produce the internal error but the second one didn't.

Answer (score 3):

From the samples given it appears to be a normal SQL injection with a string.

For argument sake, say the query was

```
select * from users where username='<user data>' ;
```

It is correct that the first two do cause an error as they produce invalid SQL:

```
select * from users where username='';--'' ;
select * from users where username='';---'' ;
```

Because with regards to [MySQL comments](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comments.html):

> the `“-- ”` (double-dash) comment style requires the second dash to be
>   followed by at least one whitespace or control character (such as a
>   space, tab, newline, and so on)

Try `';-- '`

Trailing single quote probably not needed.

The remaining produce either incomplete (i.e. no closing single quote) or valid SQL so don't produce any error:

```
select * from users where username='';--' ;
select * from users where username='";--"' ;
select * from users where username=';--'' ;
```

Note that

```
select * from users where username='';-f-'' ;
```

should error. I would confirm whether the result of this test case is correct.

Comment: thanks for the response. ';-- ' and ';-f-' doesn't give any error. and by my understanding, shouldn't ';-- and ';--' result similar outputs?

Comment: If it was a normal SQL injection, ';-- should've also produced an error.